# If value is 0, then replace with null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a variable whose value is 0 and I want to replace it with NULL in postgresql.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: See [NullIf](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-nullif-function/)? An actual example of your usecase would help.

Comment: Do you mean column rather than variable . sample data and expected outcome would help clarify.

Comment: Case handled the issue.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use an update:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET val = NULL
WHERE val = 0;
```